# How do I start RetroPie

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, retropie, lxterminal

Hei

Now I have installed RetroPie from the terminal in Raspbian, but how do I start it?
I have written **emulationstation** but then it says: *X is running. Please shut down X in order to mitigate problems with losing keyboard input. For example, logout from LXDE*.
So how do I take it from here?

Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 4):

Run raspi-config and tell it to boot to command line, not desktop. Reboot (User pi, password raspberry). Now run the emulationstation command again. If you want to load the desktop for any reason instead, type startx.

Another option is to try to find a logout button somewhere in the desktop's menus, but I don't think Raspbian has one. Feel free to correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Raspbian's default desktop is actually [LXDE](http://lxde.org/).  It probably does (or should...I've never used it) have a "logout" option, but since a [display manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_display_manager_(program_type)) is also used, it won't get you to the console; you'll just get a GUI login screen.  Changing the default user mode via `raspi-config` and using `startx` when desired is the way to go (and then logging out of LXDE will take you back to console).

Answer (score 0):

i have found a logout option under shutdown. But if you still can't find it, logout using 'shutdown -l now' in the terminal.